# Failed to listen on prefix 'http://localhost:5041/' because it conflicts with an existing registration on the machine

Tags: c#, .net-core

1. my helper class, i using HttpListener create a HttpListenerResponse with a HttpListenerRequest. But when run test it have a error "Failed to listen on prefix 'http://localhost:5041/' because it conflicts with an existing registration on the machine" everyone had this problem please help me. thanks.
   My Helper class: 
       using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
       using System;
       using System.Net;
       using System.IO;
       using System.Net.Sockets;
       using System.Text;
       using System.Collections.Generic;

   ```
   namespace ApiBusinesslogicTest
   {
   public class MockHttpResponseHelper
   {
       private readonly ILogger _logger;
       HttpListener _listener;
       int requestIndex = 0;
       Dictionary<int, HttpStatusCode> dHttpStatus; Dictionary<int, 
   MemoryStream> dResponseObject; Dictionary<int, StringBuilder> 
   dRequestData;
       public MockHttpResponseHelper(ILogger logger)
       {
           this._logger = logger;
       }

       public WebResponse CreateWebResponse(String prefix, 
   Dictionary<int, HttpStatusCode> dHttpStatus, Dictionary<int, 
   MemoryStream> dResponseObject, Dictionary<int, StringBuilder> 
   dRequestData)
       {
           this.dRequestData = dRequestData;
           this.dResponseObject = dResponseObject;
           this.dHttpStatus = dHttpStatus;
           TcpListener l = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 0);
           l.Start();
           int port = ((IPEndPoint)l.LocalEndpoint).Port;
           l.Stop();

           // Create a listener.
           // string prefix = endPoint;
           _listener = new HttpListener();
           _listener.Prefixes.Add(prefix);

           _listener.Start();
           try
           {
               _listener.BeginGetContext(new 
   AsyncCallback(clientConnect), _listener);
           }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           _logger.LogWarning(e.StackTrace);
       }

       return null;
   }

   public void stop()
   {
       _listener.Stop();
       _listener.Close();
   }

   public void clientConnect(IAsyncResult ar)
   {
       if (!_listener.IsListening) return;

       HttpListenerContext context = _listener.EndGetContext(ar);

       //_listener.BeginGetContext(clientConnect, _listener);
       HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;

       if (!request.HasEntityBody)
       {
           _logger.LogTrace("No client data was sent with the 
   request.");
           return;
       }
       System.IO.Stream body = request.InputStream;
       System.Text.Encoding encoding = request.ContentEncoding;
       System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(body, 
   encoding);
       if (request.ContentType != null)
       {
           _logger.LogTrace("Client data content type {0}", 
   request.ContentType);
       }
       _logger.LogTrace("Client data content length {0}", 
   request.ContentLength64);

       _logger.LogTrace("Start of client data:");
       // Convert the data to a string and display it on the console.
       string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
       dRequestData[requestIndex].Append(s);
       _logger.LogTrace(s);
       _logger.LogTrace("End of client data:");
       body.Close();
       reader.Close();

       // Obtain a response object.
       HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;

       response.StatusCode = (int)dHttpStatus[requestIndex];

       // Construct a response.
       if (dResponseObject != null)
       {
           byte[] buffer = dResponseObject[requestIndex].ToArray();

           // Get a response stream and write the response to it.
           Stream output = response.OutputStream;
           output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
           try
           {
               output.Flush();
               output.Close();
               response.Close();
           }
           finally
           {

               requestIndex++;
               _listener.BeginGetContext(new 
   AsyncCallback(clientConnect), _listener);
           }
       }
   }
   }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Type "netstat -ano" on CMD to check whether the port 5041 is already in use (which I assume). You could also type "netstat -anob", to see which application is using this port (requires admin rights).

If the port is in use, you should choose another port for your application.

Comment: thank for your help, i try it, but i had problem with my test class, i could not turn off parallel when run xunit, so it created multi thread listening a port, can you help me ?